# (scrolled)="onScrollDown()" getting called multiple times - Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular, infinite-scroll, nginfinitescroll

I am using [this infinite scroll library](https://github.com/orizens/angular2-infinite-scroll/) & its calling a fucntion miltiple times on scroll my code:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover inline-edit"
    infinite-scroll
    [infiniteScrollDistance]="2"
    [infiniteScrollThrottle]="10"
    (scrolled)="onScrollDown()">
onScrollDown() {
      this.pageNumber += 1;
      this.getContacts();
}
```

When it reaches viewports length it calls onScrollDown multiple times like 5/6 times

Comment: Any solution you got..??